# Format string based on word match

Tags: c++, qt

I ran out of ideas. I need to format this text creating a paragraph for each instance of the word 'Group'.

Notice Group1, Group2:

```
('uniqueName', 'Group', True ),
('Value', 'float', 0, 5, 1 ),
('Value', 'int', 1 ),
('Value', 'bool', true),
('uniqueName', 'Group', True ),
('Value', 'bool', true),
....
```

I need to separate this is in two paragraphs:

```
('uniqueName', 'Group', True ),
('Value', 'float', 0, 5, 1 ),
('Value', 'int', 1 ),
('Value', 'bool', true),

('uniqueName', 'Group', True ),
('Value', 'bool', true),
```

Each group represents the parameters below it, so Group1 have value1 - value3. The groups and values share the same pattern so is being difficult. I'm using QT with QString.

Comment: Have a counter initialised to 0, then read the file line by line, extract the type string from every line and if that one equals `Group` print a newline to the new file before copying the line to – and reset the counter to 0. If the line is no group, then increment the counter, extract the name string and append the counter to it. Finally print the line again. You might be doing the matching with a regex (two, actually), too...

Comment: *I need to format this text* -- We don't know where or how that information is stored.  There is literally no C++ code, only an abstract idea.

Comment: @Aconcagua I just noticed that I didn't type a good text example. It should be: ('uniqueName', 'Group', True ).

I tried to express the idea without code because is a text formatting question. Where the text is stored is not actually relevant, but I'm reading it line by line using a QTextStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aconcagua's comment I found a solution.
Just had to check for each Group match and add a new line before copying the line to the file. Then check for everything that was not a group and add it to the file after adding the group:

```
If(Group)
{ // add a blank line
  // Copy the group to the file
}

if(!Group)
{
  // Copy the line to the file
}
```